# Mapping the Status property between the MS Word Property and the Status SharePoint site column

Tags: sharepoint-online, word, office, status

Inside MS Office word we have the Status property as follow:-

[image]

and inside a SharePoint online site collection i added the built-in Status site column inside a document library:-

[image]

now when i upload a document the Status will be mapped between the MS office word and SharePoint. For example if a document have status = "Not Started" and i upload the document then the Status inside SharePoint will also be "Not Started" (as shown in the above 2 pictures)... but the issue i am facing is that the Status inside MS Office word will be a free text while inside SharePoint it will be a drop-down, so the status inside MS office word can contain a value not inside the drop-down choices as in the "Not Started" case.. so how i can fix this issue? either by modifying the MS office word property or the SharePoint site column?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing we can do. The document properties do not have a column setting in Word client similar to the one in SharePoint library, yet changing the settings in SharePoint will not affect the properties in Word either.

Another thing you should notice, since there is no choice type in the default document properties, the **Status** column in SharePoint will not be accepted as the same property but adding a another one in Word client.

However, the choice field will not pass values to any side when being edit, it just keeps the SharePoint settings but does nothing. The Choice field in SharePoint will use the value from Text field (original document properties), so will the Quick Part in Word.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but can you explain your answer in more details ?

Comment: @SharePointTestDev Which part do you need for details?

Comment: the following `the Status column in SharePoint will not be accepted as the same property but adding a another one in Word client.

However, the choice field will not pass values to any side when being edit, it just keeps the SharePoint settings but does nothing. The Choice field in SharePoint will use the value from Text field (original document properties), so will the Quick Part in Word.`

Comment: @SharePointTestDev There is a second Status column after the sync, see the screenshot I provide (not sure if you can see that from your end). That’s the choice column from SharePoint, proofing that SharePoint does not accept the Text field Status as the same column, so it adds another one as “SharePoint Properties”. But if we change the value of the second column, it does not pass to SharePoint. These two products are not corresponding that well, so we cannot really do anything about it. SharePoint reads the value from the Text field anyway.